# XQuery Transformation without hardcoding XML document

Tags: xml, xquery, oxygenxml

I am using the oXygen XML editor, and have defined a series of XQuery transformations.

The problem is, as of right now the input xml needs to be declared as:

```
let $k := doc("path")
```

I was wondering if there was some way of replacing `doc("path")` with the content of the file defined in the transformation scenario?[image]

(Ie: in this case untitled.xml)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try clicking on `Parameters (0)` and adding a new parameter `URL` with value of `${currentFileURL}`. Then in your script prolog declare an external variable:

```
declare variable $URL external;
```

Then you should be able to reference `doc($URL)`, and if the XML URL changes in Oxygen, it should pass through to your XQuery script.